# R system.file does not work as documented? (Or is just confusing?)

Tags: r, package, filepath

I am very confused by the R manual. According to the help pages, the `system.file` function may be used to find files relative to their installed path

```
> system.file("help", "AnIndex", package = "splines")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/splines/help/AnIndex"
```

Ok, so then I would expect that a file in my own package would also be obtainable using the same mechanism, but:

```
> library(reindeer)
> system.file("inst","default_parmeters.xlsx",package="reindeer",mustWork = TRUE)
Error in system.file("inst", "default_parmeters.xlsx", package = "reindeer",  : 
  no file found
```

This hacky version works though:

```
> file.path(system.file(package="reindeer",mustWork = TRUE),"inst","default_parmeters.xlsx")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/reindeer/inst/default_parmeters.xlsx"
```

I cannot see why? This behaviour seems very arbitrary to me right.

Comment: There's no `inst` folder in an installed package. Everything in the `inst` folder of the package source goes to the root folder. So that should work if you remove `"inst"`.

Comment: How exactly did you build and install your package? As already mentioned, during the build process everything from inst should be copied to the main package root. Do you have an inst folder in your inst folder? Or were you trying to develop your package directly in your library path?

Comment: Sorry, yes. The fact that a file path may be created to a file does not mean that it exists. Indeed, "inst" files are installed under the root of the package, and there it is now. Sorry!